# Python Pandas How to make pct_change() calculate the change from a single number instead of previous numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

`20.4417
20.5679
20.0826
20.9950
20.0244
19.1702
19.3546
19.1702
19.7138
19.3546`

I want to figure out what the percent change is between the first value `20.4417`and every value that follows it.  The pandas `pct_change()` function returns the change from values that are next to each other and when I try to put the first value of the Series into `pct_change()` I think it's taking that as the period and giving me `nan's` up to that point.  Does anyone know how to get it to take a parameter and do the percent change between that parameter and every element of the series? Here's my code:

`s2 = s1.pct_change(s1[0])`

Comment: what's wrong with just writing the 1-line mathematical formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

```
s2 = s1 / s1[0] - 1
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

First thing that popped into my head was to just add another column and then do percent change over `axis=1`.

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.DataFrame(
    [20.4417,
    20.5679,
    20.0826,
    20.9950,
    20.0244,
    19.1702,
    19.3546,
    19.1702,
    19.7138,
    19.3546])

f['added_col'] = [f[0][0] for i in range(len(f))] # Create column where each element is the first item in the first column
f = f[f.columns[::-1]] # flip our columns so we compare in the right order
print f.pct_change(axis=1)[0]
```

which outputs:

```
0    0.000000
1    0.006174
2   -0.017567
3    0.027067
4   -0.020414
5   -0.062201
6   -0.053181
7   -0.062201
8   -0.035609
9   -0.053181
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```